# How to change Windows DPI without restart?

Tags: windows-7, windows, resolution, dpi

It's fairly simple to adjust your DPI by editing the registry path HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG\Software\Fonts, and if you want to apply the changes, you either need to restart your computer or log-off then log back on.

I noticed if I switch users, it will change the DPI for the login screen, but not my desktop. Is there any way to change the DPI (restart a service and/or process) to apply the changes without having to log out?

Answer (score 0):

I think restarting the explorer.exe might do it, not sure though. Go to task Manager->Processes->Then right click explorer.exe->end process-> then Go to file in the task manager window->then New task(run)->then type "explorer.exe" without these -  "->press enter->tell us the results->???->PROFIT!!!!

Comment: This is **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).